RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1024) must match the size of tensor b (640) at non-singleton dimension 1
I do the instructions below:
We provide an example below for training an open-vocabulary object detector on COCO dataset, with pretrained RegionCLIP (ResNet50) as the initialization.
Before training, please prepare our pretrained RegionCLIP model and set up the dataset.
Check MODEL_ZOO.md to
download the pretrained RegionCLIP checkpoint regionclip_pretrained-cc_rn50.pth to the folder ./pretrained_ckpt/regionclip,
download the trained RPN checkpoint rpn_coco_48.pth to the folder ./pretrained_ckpt/rpn,
download the class embeddings coco_48_base_cls_emb.pth and coco_65_cls_emb.pth to the folder ./pretrained_ckpt/concept_emb.
Check datasets/README.md to set up COCO dataset.
After preparation, run the following script to train an open-vocabulary detector.

python3 ./tools/train_net.py \
--num-gpus 1 \
--config-file ./configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/CLIP_fast_rcnn_R_50_C4_ovd.yaml \
MODEL.WEIGHTS ./pretrained_ckpt/regionclip/regionclip_pretrained-cc_rn50.pth \
MODEL.CLIP.OFFLINE_RPN_CONFIG ./configs/COCO-InstanceSegmentation/mask_rcnn_R_50_C4_1x_ovd_FSD.yaml \
MODEL.CLIP.BB_RPN_WEIGHTS ./pretrained_ckpt/rpn/rpn_coco_48.pth \
MODEL.CLIP.TEXT_EMB_PATH ./pretrained_ckpt/concept_emb/coco_48_base_cls_emb.pth \
MODEL.CLIP.OPENSET_TEST_TEXT_EMB_PATH ./pretrained_ckpt/concept_emb/coco_65_cls_emb.pth \

I want to train my own dataset and categories, so I modified the dataset configuration in the configs and have already changed the `NUM_CLASSES`.

And I got error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/./tools/train_net.py", line 173, in <module>
    launch(
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/engine/launch.py", line 67, in launch
    mp.spawn(
  File "/home/u9347822/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 230, in spawn
    return start_processes(fn, args, nprocs, join, daemon, start_method='spawn')
  File "/home/u9347822/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 188, in start_processes
    while not context.join():
  File "/home/u9347822/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 150, in join
    raise ProcessRaisedException(msg, error_index, failed_process.pid)
torch.multiprocessing.spawn.ProcessRaisedException:

-- Process 0 terminated with the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/u9347822/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/multiprocessing/spawn.py", line 59, in _wrap
    fn(i, *args)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/engine/launch.py", line 125, in _distributed_worker
    main_func(*args)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/tools/train_net.py", line 161, in main
    trainer = Trainer(cfg)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 377, in __init__
    model = self.build_model(cfg)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/engine/defaults.py", line 517, in build_model
    model = build_model(cfg)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/build.py", line 22, in build_model
    model = META_ARCH_REGISTRY.get(meta_arch)(cfg)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/config/config.py", line 174, in wrapped
    explicit_args = _get_args_from_config(from_config_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/config/config.py", line 229, in _get_args_from_config
    ret = from_config_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/modeling/meta_arch/clip_rcnn.py", line 146, in from_config
    roi_heads = build_roi_heads(cfg, backbone.output_shape())
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/modeling/roi_heads/roi_heads.py", line 43, in build_roi_heads
    return ROI_HEADS_REGISTRY.get(name)(cfg, input_shape)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/config/config.py", line 174, in wrapped
    explicit_args = _get_args_from_config(from_config_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/config/config.py", line 229, in _get_args_from_config
    ret = from_config_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/modeling/roi_heads/clip_roi_heads.py", line 101, in from_config
    ret["box_predictor"] = FastRCNNOutputLayers(
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/config/config.py", line 175, in wrapped
    init_func(self, **explicit_args)
  File "/home/u9347822/RegionCLIP/detectron2/modeling/roi_heads/fast_rcnn.py", line 453, in __init__
    self.cls_score.weight.copy_(pre_computed_w)
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (1024) must match the size of tensor b (640) at non-singleton dimension 1

I tried to adjust MIN_SIZE_TRAIN in the configs from (640, 672, 704, 736, 768, 800) to (1024, 672, 704, 736, 768, 800), but I still got the same error.

Hi, welcome to Stackoverlfow ! Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Very few people will be willing to download and prepare your pretrained model and datasets to debug a tensor size question. At the very least, can you tell us what is the shape of the tensors in the original dataset and what is the shape of the tensors in your custom dataset ?
